# React Hooks - Select Option value and name in the same method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have the following situation where i want to get due different values to set the State ( item.id and item.name ) when i select an item in my dropdown. At the moment i can only do for 1 value ( item.id )

How can i do in the same method, is this possible?

This is the code

```
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");
  const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState("");

  const selectValue = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setSelectedValue(value);
  };

  <select value={selectedValue} onChange={selectValue}>
     {teamsDetail && teamsDetail.length > 0
        ? teamsDetail.map(item => (
           <option key={`${item.team_id}`} value={item.team_id}>
             {item.name}
           </option>
              ))
            : null}
   </select>

{selectedValue}
{selectedName} ??
```

The question is how can i now add the same logic also for te name value in in order to display for example the `selectedName`?

I provide the demo here => https://codesandbox.io/s/select-demo-u1o1k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name from `teamDetail` based on `id`

```
const selectValue = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const item = teamsDetail.find(item => item.id == value);
    setSelectedValue(value);
    setSelectedName(item.name);
  };
```

or you could get value using `nativeEvent` to get option text like

```
 const selectValue = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const index = evt.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
    const text = evt.nativeEvent.target[index].text;
    setSelectedValue(value);
    setSelectedName(text);
  };
```

Comment: ok thanks, can you provide to me also the content in the <select></select> for accepting the answer? It looks also that part should be modified

Comment: There is nothing you need to change in the render method, everything will remain as it is, only the selectValue function needs to change

Comment: First solution it is actually not working because
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: I made a typo there. Should have used `teamsDetail.find` and not `teamDetail.find`. Also use `==` instead of `===` in case the type of values returned are different

Comment: thanks but it was not because of these changes, there is not a an event target for the name thats why it is undefined, i will provide a demo

Comment: Do you have a separate select field for name, it didn't seem so from your question

Comment: I have provided the demo with your solution

Comment: @Koala7 you were destructuring item from the result of .find which is why you had the issue. Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-demo-3s87y. Notice the difference: `const item = items.find(item => item.id === value);`(right way) vs `const { item }= items.find(item => item.id === value);`(wrong way)